# Is the ellipse made in the mentioned sentence idiomatic?

Tags: ellipsis, idiomatic-language

> 1. Lisa is entitled not to be deceived on X as much as is entitled not to
>      be deceive on Y.
> 2. Lisa is entitled not to be deceived on X as much as **she** is entitled
>      not to be deceive on Y.

In the first sentence above, *she* is dropped. Is such an ellipse idiomatic?

Answer (score 1):

No, such an ellipsis is not idiomatic.  The word "she" must be included.

> Lisa is entitled not to be deceived on *X* as much as **she** is entitled not to be deceived on *Y*.

Comment: So, as another example, is "The answer for the current question is not as plain *as was* for the previous question" not grammatical?

Comment: I'd say it is ungrammatical, although I don't have time just now to work out or look up what the rule is.  To take an even simpler example, "He ran as fast today as ran yesterday" is ungrammatical.  You can either say "...as yesterday" or "...as he ran yesterday".  Usually, "as was" is interpreted as "as was [subject]" (i.e. "as [subject] was" inverted), e.g. "Jim was angry, as was Sally".

Answer (score 0):

It is terrible, but the quickest solution is to shorten it a bit:

> Lisa is ***as*** entitled not to be deceived on ***Y*** as she is on ***X***.

It's also a little better to use a positive (*She is entitled to [be told] the truth ...*) but that's a style issue rather than a correctness one.

Comment: Yes, but would that be a good way to go when Y and X are quite longer?

Comment: Fair point. I'd suggest though that if they are that long as to be a problem, describing them in turn, *then* adding "... *she is just as entitled to know the truth about the Y as she it about the X."