# Is the repetition of "one" as pronoun in the mentioned sentence idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language, repetition

> **One** is entitled not to be mislead on the color of what **one** is shown as
>   much as is entitled not to be mislead on the shape of what **one** is
>   shown.

One is repeated 3 times. Sounds redundant to me. Is it idiomatic?

Comment: You are missing one one: as much as one is entitled. Put in another pronoun> she or he or we or they or you. You will see.

Comment: @Lambie What about the repetition?

Comment: She is entitled to not be mislead on the color of what she is shown as much as she is entitled not to be mislead on the shape of what she is shown. I asked you to do that so you could "feel" it. The  pronouns are all required.

Answer (score 2):

One needs one more one in this one and two less of whats.

> One is entitled not to be mislead on the color one is shown as much as one is entitled not to be mislead on the shape one is shown.

Answer (score 2):

In BrE and most varieties of AmE, "one" acts as a full personal pronoun, so it cannot be replaced by "he" or "they":

> One must do it oneself.
>
> One should try not to lose one's keys.

Some AmE speakers permit an alternative construction in which, after the initial "one", the following instances can be replaced:

> One must do it himself (*or* themselves).
>
> One should try not to lose his (*or* their) keys.

In your example, you could get away with saying "is shown" in place of "one is shown", but the meaning would be slightly different (since one is no longer necessarily the person being shown).  However, you need "as one is", not "as is".

> One is entitled not to be mislead on the color of what one is shown as much as one is entitled not to be mislead on the shape of what one is shown.

Comment: Can your point on "as is/as one is" be generalized? I have asked this question here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/150244/is-the-ellipse-made-in-the-mentioned-sentence-idiomatic

Comment: Yes, it can.  I've now posted an answer to your linked question.

Comment: I don't think the question was about the usage of the pronoun one. Anyway, the OP left one out.

Comment: I addressed the usage of the pronoun *one*.  I also addressed the fact that the OP missed one required *one* out.